# Connect to an Android simulator with C#

Tags: c#, android, adb

I have an Android app that I want to run in an Android simulator. How should I connect to an Android simulator for accessing that app in the simulator? Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the Android Debug Bridge from C#, try the [SharpAdbClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpAdbClient/2.2.0-beta457) NuGet package, which I maintain. (The source code is on GitHub: https://github.com/quamotion/madb)

For example, if you want to list all Android devices connected to your PC, you could use something like this:

```
AdbServer server = new AdbServer();
var result = server.StartServer(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe", restartServerIfNewer: false);

var devices = AdbClient.Instance.GetDevices();

foreach(var device in devices)
{
     Console.WriteLine(device.Name);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: How can i connect to Nox Player or other emulators using `SharpAdbClient`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Android Debug Bridge](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html). to connect, debug, install debug APK.

If your not using any IDE like xamarin or android studio. use `adb install`  or `adb connect` to connect on android on terminal. adb can be found inside the android SDK

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html

Comment: any guide for c#

Comment: do you use xamarin? or visual studio? try installing https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/mobile-app-development/#downloadvs this mobile development is c# base

Comment: i use visual studio to make it clear im making form and want to access android simulator like those simulators (nox,bluestacks,koplayer,leapdroid....etc)